# Saving previous values of a Tensorflow.js tensor

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, if-statement, optimization, tensor

I have an function which stores all of the values of the tensor and then concatonates it into one matrix. The function looks like this:

```
    if (i == 1) {
        var y_pred1 = y_pred
    } else if (i == 2) {
        var y_pred2 = y_pred
    } else if (i == 3) {
        var y_pred3 = y_pred
    } else if (i == 4) {
        var y_pred4 = y_pred
    }
tf.concat([y_pred1, y_pred2, y_pred3, y_pred4])
```

This function stores every value of `y_pred` across every iteration of for a loop. Is there a way to make this more efficient so that I do not need to have an obscure amount of if statements inside of the model. For your information `y_pred` is a tensor.

FYI: `i` stands for the iteration number so if iteration 1 is reached `y_pred1 = y_pred`

Comment: You'r code is incomplete, please at least include you'r loop. Otherwise, everyone is just assuming you're using a `while` a `for`or a `for in`, also the declaration and value of `y_pred` is missing. For a correct optimization we need all that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every tensors return a result, you probably should use an instance of `Array`.

If the number of tensor if static and you know it in advance:

```
var tf = new Array(number_of_tensors);

for (var i = 0; i < number_of_tensors; i++) {
    var y_pred = /** get the result of your tensor **/
    tf[i] = y_pred;
}
```

And that's all. No need to `concat()`, `tf` is already a matrix.

If you don't know the number of tensors:

```
// before your for-loop
var tf = new Array();

// into your for-loop
var y_pred = /** get the result of your tensor **/
tf.push(y_pred);
```